# SwiftUI AsyncImage animation misbehavior

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-asyncimage

While testing out SwiftUI, I've found that AsyncImage does not work well while animating a transition. It seems to settle on its final position of the transition before the rest of the UI has moved there, making the animation seem weird or off.

My main question is: is there any way to access the SwiftUI animation of the AsyncImage and make it work with other animations elsewhere in the app?

[image]

The weird part is that, if I change it to some other view (that doesn't have animations), the transition behaves correctly, so I believe that the root of the problem is something to do with AsyncImage's default animation for changing between its `phases` (loading, failed or loaded).

The overlay that is presented is described as such:

```
    if isBottomSheetVisible {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    AccountSelectorHeader()
                    ForEach(accounts) { account in
                        AccountRow(
                            account: account,
                            isLast: accounts.last == account
                        )
                    }
                }
                .padding(.bottom, 24)
                .background(Color(.tableViewHeaderBackgroundColor)
                                .cornerRadius(24, corners: [.topLeft, .topRight])
                                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
                )
                .transition(
                    .move(edge: .bottom)
                )
            }
```

And each image is only a standard AsyncImage inside the AccountRow view:

```
    AsyncImage(url: URL(string: account.image)) {
            $0
                .resizable()
                .clipShape(Circle())
        } placeholder: {
            ProgressView()
        }
```

Comment: FWIW- I was having a similar issue and when I replaced the AsyncImage with a custom view that loaded an image, it animated properly, so seems like a bug in AsyncImage

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I faced a similar issue and it worked fairly well if you use the  `init(url:scale:transaction:content:)`.

With the code below I got the image move in with the sheet and on disappear it didn't move but was removed as the sheet obscured it:

```
AsyncImage(
            url: URL(string: url),
            transaction: Transaction(animation: .default)
        ) { phase in
            switch phase {
            case .success(let image):
                image
                    .resizable()
            default:
                Image("defaultImage")
                    .resizable()
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's indeed weird, just tried with an own implementation of asyncImage and it has a similar behaviour, perhaps it is easier for you to fix it from there: [Simple iOS13 AsyncImage](https://github.com/MarcBiosca/AsyncImage). I will take a look to it too if I have time.